# How to fix the error: "The function should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope. "

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to sum traded volume in a specific price range (dgt_2 >= x and dgt_2 < y), each time price changes calculation starts again.
It works but TV shows the warning: The function 'math.sum' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

```
var counter_1 = 0
if dgt_2 >= x and dgt_2 < y and dgt_2[n] == dgt_2[n+1]
    counter_1 += 1
else
    counter_1 := 0

var counter_Volume_1 = 0
if dgt_2 >= x and dgt_2 < y and dgt_2[n] == dgt_2[n+1]
    counter_Volume_1 := int(math.sum(volume, counter_1))
else
    counter_Volume_1 := 0
```

I've tried to replace math.sum function with another one with the same result:

```
VS(v, c) => int(math.sum(v, c))

var counter_Volume_1 = 0
if dgt_2 >= x and dgt_2 < y and dgt_2[n] == dgt_2[n+1]
    counter_Volume_1 := VS(volume, counter_1)
else
    counter_Volume_1 := 0
```

How to fix the error?
This is my first script, sorry if a solution is too obvious. Thank you!

Comment: It's not error but a warning. Tradingview wants to execute the `math.sum` on every bar for consistency. However, with your if condition, you are limiting when this function will be called. In your case, I believe you can ignore this warning.

Comment: ok, thanks, will ignore this!